# SQL Server query: pair each record from table 1 to all record at table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Guys I am having a hard time searching for this, I just can't properly write it in words.. but it's like this. attached image -->

[MY PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07wph.png)

Comment: No. You have to write it in words. Try harder.

Comment: You need a CROSS JOIN

Comment: @Blorgbeard , i have attached an image :)

Comment: @qxg oh thanks lemme try

Comment: At least you can make the image inline.

Comment: @qxg im new in stackoverflow and registered for this reason.. but thanks it's a big help man! thank you again

Comment: Next time please desist from linking images and put the sample data in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [CROSS JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx).

```
SELECT TABLE1.BAKESHOP_NO, TABLE2.PRODUCT_NO
FROM TABLE1 CROSS JOIN TABLE2
ORDER BY BAKESHOP_NO, PRODUCT_NO
```

Comment: WHOOAAA it's a dumb question but twas bothering me for a month on how to do it.. it did work! thank you very much